# Getting a Video ID from a YT URL then inserting it inside a Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I already know that there are answers for this question but they don't really show how to implement the answer, and since I'm new to programming I can't get it to work.

My website is an HTML page that has a text area where the user enters a Youtube Video URL and then clicks a button which takes the Video ID out and inserts it in the bottom text area.

### Update

I have removed the unnecessary parts eg. Names. Pictures.

[image]

So the User enters the YT URL in the "Youtube Video URL" Text area then clicks the "click to generate the new video URL" in which it gets placed in the "Generated New Video URL" with a new address in front e.g.

"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYix0rw_FAw" - GETS ENTERED

BUTTON IS CLICKED

"www.Testing.com/YYix0rw_FAw" - IS OUTPUTTED

Comment: There are several ways to meet your objective, let's narrow down possibilities by seeing what you have done in code so far. Post your code as a [mcve].

Comment: I have better revised the question with more information and images, hope you can help :)

Comment: Is there an advantage or reason why a YT URL needs to be changed to...another URL? This fictional url someplace other than a YT domain?

Comment: I cannot say much with my problem, but our devices are stating that a YT video Is flagged and not able to be watched on my systems, But placing it inside another webpage inside a Iframe allows the Video to be watched. I do apologize but I really cannot show/say more, Just looking for a solution to my specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo uses the following:

- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [**ES6 Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [**.insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

**Details are commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
/* HTMLFormControlsCollection
 - Requires: <form>
 - Form Controls (FC): <input>, <button>, <select>, <textarea>, <output>, and <fieldset>
 - All FC must be inside <form> 
 - Each FC needs an #id and/or name
 - Very easy way to reference FC:
 (see code below):   
*/
// Forms interface
//=================
// .forms.IDorName or .forms[IDorName]
var form = document.forms.main;

// .elements property accesses ALL FC
var ctrl = form.elements;

// Referencing elements of Form
var bttn = ctrl.bttn;

// Register click event on <button>
bttn.onclick = function(e) {

  // Get user text input
  const IN = ctrl.text.value;

  // Extract the last 11 charaters
  var ID = IN.substring(IN.length - 11);

  // Verifying
  console.log(ID);

  /* Template Literals
  It's String Literals using new and powerful syntax:
  
  1. SL: common quotes: ' "
     TL: uncommon backticks: `
  2. SL: ....'+ VAR +'....
     TL: ....${VAR}.....
  */
  var URL = `http://phoney.fak/${ID}`;

  /* .insertAdjacentHTML('LOCATION', `STRING to be rendered as HTML`)`
   */

  ctrl.view.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', URL + '<br>');

}
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <input id='text'>
  <input id='bttn' type='button' value='GO'>
  <output id='view'></output>
</form>



<br><br><br>
<h3>TEST</h3>
<p>Copy &amp; Paste each of these URLS into the input above</p>
<ul>
  <li>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0u4M6vppCI</li>
  <li>https://youtu.be/U9t-slLl30E</li>
  <li>https://youtu.be/4r7wHMg5Yjg</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, This is flat out amazing thank you greatly, I haven't the time currently but will do later, to implement the code. So i'll update when I can. Thank you again

Comment: @T.script that's great, I'm glad I could help. If this answer is adequate, click the checkmark ✔ of this post in order to accept it.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, but the code is to confusing for me, can you show how this can be changed to output to another text box? and is this javascript or Jquery as I would preferably like it in javascript. Amazing start and I appreciate it

Comment: It's plain JavaScript and I can see how the code can be confusing. Despite its simplicity, it is terse, and not easy to follow unless one has a grasp of JS fundamentals.  The `<output>` can be replaced with an `<input>` seamlessly. In this setup `<output>` is exactly like `<input readonly>`. As for an explanation of the code itself, I would need to assess your own code in order to help you. The code in this answer has comments on each line and to go any further without knowing exactly what you do or don't understand, I'd end up writing a tutorial. Before you try to integrate this answer...

Comment: ...within your code, copy and paste the code on a blank html file (<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>{{{CODE HERE}}}</body></html>`).  If successful, you have a working code that you can apply other components to progressively. Once again I cannot feasibly give you any useful help if I have no idea as to what you've already tried or already know because I have yet to see any of your code.

Comment: Yep I managed to get this to work thanks to you comment :D. Thank you sooo much Its really appreciated. I'm accepting this as my answer :)

Comment: That's great, I knew you were close to resolving it, happy coding.